# showDialog() called, but no dialog box on screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

Until recently, I've been using showDialog() and hideDialog() with no issues.  I just added a new Activity to my project, and now for some reason I'm not able to produce a dialog box in the new Activity.

The call is pretty simple:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_ID);

// do some work off the main thread

hideDialog(DIALOG_ID);
```

With the dialog management like this:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    switch (id) {       
    case DIALOG_ID:
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("LOADING ...");
        break;

    default:
        dialog = null;
    }

    return dialog;
}
```

In the debugger, I can see that onCreateDialog() is being called with the right ID, and the correct case is executing therein ... but the dialog box never shows up on the screen.  I also tried calling dialog.show() explicitly, but that didn't help.

This should be simple: What's preventing the dialog box from appearing?  Thanks.

Comment: you want a dialog(message box as i understand) to just show the message, right? but then hide it again, well i have how to show  a dialog(message box) but with a Ok button .. if helps?

Comment: Sure, let's see how you do it - thanks.

Comment: check my answer anything just comment it

Comment: btw i was reading your code there and try taking out the "default: dialog = null; " and see what it happens?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the code is working now.  The change I made was to move the working lines "// do some work off the main thread" to an IntentService.  So the dialog did not appear when the showDialog/hideDialog calls surrounded other function calls in the same Activity ... but did work when the working lines were moved away from the UI and into a separate IntentService (where they should be, since the work involves getting data from a server).  Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: you're welcome glad to help ( i guess ) haha.

Answer (score 1):

Code to show the message:

```
                 ShowMessage("Title","Message goes here");
```

and the "ShowMessage" void:

```
  public void ShowMessage(String titulo,String msg){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
        dialogo.setMessage(msg);        
        dialogo.setTitle(titulo);       
        dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);       
        dialogo.show();
    }
```